# A relatively compact family of probability measures that is not tight

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

We know, thanks to Prokhorov's theorem, that a family of probability measures $\mathcal{H}$ in a metric space $X$ is tight if, and only if, it's relatively compact whenever $X$ is polish.

The implication known as Prokhorov's direct half which states that the tightness of $\mathcal{H}$ implies the relative compactness of $\mathcal{H}$ does not require the metric space $X$ to be polish. This hypothesis is only required for the inverse half, that is: A family of probability measures $\mathcal{H}$ on a polish space is tight whenever it is relatively compact.

Is there an example of a family of probability measures on a (not polish) metric space that is relatively compact but fails to be tight?

Comment: A single measure $\mu$ on a metric space need not be tight and in this case family $\{\mu\}$ consisting of only one measure would be weakly (relatively) compact but not tight. Talagrand and Fremlin constucted a gaussian measure on $l^\infty$ with this property, in a paper "A gaussian measure on $\ell^\infty$". The idea is to take independent gaussian random variables $X_n \sim \mathcal N(0, \frac{1}{\ln(n+2)})$, form a vector $(X_n)_{n \ge 0}$ on the space $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ (which gives some probability measure $\mu_0$) and define $\mu$ as a restriction of $\mu_0$ to $\ell^\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

This is taken from volume $2$ of Bogachev's "Measure Theory", Example $8.6.9$.

Consider $X = \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$, where all points in $\mathbb{N}$ are open and the neighbourhoods of $\{\infty\}$ are of the form $U\cup \{\infty\}$ with $U\subset \mathbb{N}$ satisfying
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \#\left(U\cap [[1,n]]\right) = 1.$$

Then

1. $n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_i$ converges weakly to $\delta_\infty$. Indeed, if $U\subset X$ is an open neighbourhood of $\{\infty\}$, then $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_i(U) = n^{-1}\#\left(U\cap [[1,n]]\right)\to 1 = \delta_\infty (U)$. On the other hand, if $U$ is an open set not containing $\infty$, then $\delta_\infty(U) = 0\leq \liminf_n n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_i(U)$. Thus weak convergence follows from the portmanteau theorem.
2. $n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_i$ is not tight. Indeed, using that a compact subset of $X$ is necessarily finite (see below), we have $ n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_i(X\setminus K)\to 1$ for any compact set $K\subset X$.

---

Proof of the claim: Any infinite sequence $\{n_k\}\subset \mathbb{n}$ contains a subsequence $\{n_{k_i}\}$ such that its complement $U$ is open. Then $U\cup \{n_{k_i}\} $ is an open cover of $\{n_k\}\cup \{\infty\}$ that has no finite subcover.

Comment: I think the author mentions that this space is not metrizable?

Comment: @Snoop oops you're right. I missed that OP is specifically asking for a metric space.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to find an example on a metric (or metrizable) space. This is still a really good answer. Thank you.